# using bean: write inside html:form action

Tags: html, forms, struts, action, javabeans

Hope you guys can help me out, i can't find any tutorials online regarding this.

How can you use a

```
<bean:write....>
```

inside a

```
<html:form....>
```

My code is like:

```
<html:form action="/restricted/client/social/NewsFeedAction.do?action=REPLY&id=<bean:write name='adminFeed' property='id'/>">
```

then when i check the id value through debugging its just

```
<bean:write name='adminFeed' property='id'/>
```

instead of the ID value like 555 or so...

I can confirm that this bean write tag works as can use that within a

```
<a href...>
```

tag no problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tag inside another tag.
I use small workaround.

```
<bean:define id="myId" name='adminFeed' property='id'/>
<html:form action="/restricted/client/social/NewsFeedAction.do?action=REPLY&id=${myId}">
```

Comment: Hi, this unfortunately doesn't work, it only prints out ${myId} as the ID